# dispatch mouseEvent to inner component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, jtree

I have a treeTable looks like [this tutorial](http://www.hameister.org/JavaSwingTreeTable.html). and I want to let tree nodes can be drag an drop, However all mouse event is intercepted by JTable. I tried to use eventQueue and dispatch mouseEvent from table to tree, mouse pressed and release is works but drag event didn't. Is there a better way to achieve drag and drop on treeTable?

```
    var queue : EventQueue = object : EventQueue() {
    override fun dispatchEvent(event: AWTEvent) {
        if(event is MouseEvent){
               tree.dispatchEvent(event)
        }
        println(event)
        super.dispatchEvent(event)
    }
}

tree.toolkit.systemEventQueue.push(queue)
```

Comment: [sample is like this](http://www.hameister.org/JavaSwingTreeTable.html) I want to let it can be drag and drop

Comment: That's in German, and i'm not going to read through a tutorial. Follow the instructions in my link.